# Fixed height in horizontallistview does not show the correct height

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using the `HorizontalListView` provided [here](https://github.com/vieux/Android-Horizontal-ListView/blob/master/HorizontalListView.java), and I'm trying to show custom views with a fixed height and width, like this:

```
public class MyView extends View {

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setBackgroundColor((int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        int h = getHeight(); // shows 255, correct height
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int w = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(425, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int h = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(255, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        super.onMeasure(w, h);
    }

}
```

When showing this `MyView` in a normal `LinearLayout`, the height and width are perfect. However, when I show the view in the `HorizontalListView`, the width is perfect, but the height is not. See this screenshot:

[image]

The width is 425px, which is correct, the height is only 160px instead of 255.

In the source of the `HorizontalListView` there is this method:

```
private void addAndMeasureChild(final View child, int viewPos) {
    LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
    if(params == null) {
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    }

    addViewInLayout(child, viewPos, params, true);
    child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
}
```

Is there something I should change in this method, or is there something else to make this work?

Comment: Can you show us where you defined the HorizontalListView height?

Comment: I defined that in the xml, with a value of 200dp. The dark banner is the background of the `HorizontalListView`.

Comment: With that said.. I have a transparent actionbar, thus I was using `android:paddingTop="63dp"` and `android:paddingBottom="15dp"`. When removing these two lines the height of the items are right. Thanks for letting me look in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `int h = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(255, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);`, that 255 value is a PX value. If you said the height was 200 **DP** in the XML that value will be adjusted according to the device. Not sure if the screen shown is HDPI or XHDPI (my guess is the latter), it will be multiplied, so your 200 DP becomes 300 PX in an HDPI phone (x1.5). You can either use a PX value in the XML or you can define a [dimension](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) DP value that's 200DP in a values.xml.

The preference would be the latter. You can use that dimension value in your XML and retrieve that from the Resources when you create your View. That means that if at some point you want to make it bigger you can just change one value and you're done.

**Edit**

I see you found the real problem. In any case, you should still use the dimension approach, it will make your code cleaner and it will work in any phone (255 will only look right in a specific combination).

Comment: Thanks for your effort! The 255px value is actually a parameter which has already been converted from a dp value. I didn't include this to keep the code readable ;)